# Rank one decomposition or elementary tensor decomposition of matrices over commutative rings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, finite-fields, tensors

I'm facing the following problem:

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix over a commutative ring $R$ (to begin with, a finite field would be sufficient too) and want to compute a decomposition in terms of elementary tensors (or in other words rank 1 matrices). That is, $$A=\sum_{i=1}^{r} a_i\otimes b_i$$ with $a_i\in R^m$, $b_i\in R^n$ and $r$ is the rank of the matrix.

All literature I found was about matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or about singular value decomposition and so on, but nothing that is applicable to finite fields or rings. I'm looking for algorithms and literature about this problem. Does anyone have an idea?

Cheers.

Comment: Over any field a rank $r$ matrix is equivalent to a matrix having $r$ ones on the main diagonal and zero otherwise. (This can be extended to a PID, but then on the main diagonal can find $r$ non-zero elements.)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how to get the desired decomposition from this? Let $B$ be the matrix with $r$ ones on the main diagonal and zero otherwise. Then there are $m\times m$ and $n\times n$ square matrices $P$ and $Q$, such that $A=PBQ$. I'm not sure how I can use this.

Comment: Write $B$ as a sum of $r$ matrices having just one $1$ on the main diagonal (so these have rank one), and notice that its rank remains the same after multiplication by invertible matrices.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I'll try to use it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following construction covers many a ring $R$, at least all the fields and I think also PIDs.

Assume that the row space of $A$ is, or is contained in, a free $R$-module $V\subseteq R^n$ of rank $r$. Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_r$ be a basis of $V$.
So if we consider the row $v_j, j=1,2,\ldots,m$, then there exist coefficients
$b_{ij}\in R$ such that
$$
v_j=\sum_ib_{ij}a_i.
$$
Let then $b_i$ be the column vector $(b_{ij})_{1\le j\le m}$. The elementary tensor $a_i\otimes b_i$ is then a matrix with the $j$th row equal to $b_{ij}a_i$. Therefore 
$$A=\sum_i a_i\otimes b_i.$$

Comment: That certainly does the job and is very elementary. Thank you for this input. I'll try to work with it and when it solves my problem I will accept this answer.